# Making a call to a web service through a java client

Tags: web-services, soap

I have a web service running on my local apache tomcat. I can successfully talk to it via SoapUI. However, when I write a client in Java, it does not give me a response !

Here is the client code:

```
    SOAPConnectionFactory myFct = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection myCon = myFct.createConnection();
    MessageFactory myMsgFct = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = myMsgFct.createMessage();
    SOAPPart mySPart = message.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope myEnvp = mySPart.getEnvelope();
    SOAPBody body = myEnvp.getBody();
    Name bodyName = myEnvp.createName("Ping", "ws","http://ws.myeclipseide.com/");
    SOAPBodyElement gltp = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
    Name myContent1 = myEnvp.createName("arg0");
    SOAPElement mySymbol1 = gltp.addChildElement(myContent1);
    mySymbol1.addTextNode("test");
    message.saveChanges();

    URLEndpoint endPt = new URLEndpoint("http://localhost:8080/PingWebService/StringPingPort?WSDL");
    SOAPMessage reply = myCon.call(message, endPt);
    myCon.close();
    System.out.println("Response: "+reply.getContentDescription());
```

The call through soapUI looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.myeclipseide.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:Ping>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>testing this</arg0>
      </ws:Ping>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any idea why it would not work through java???

Answer (score 0):

> Does not work

Exception, error message, no call,... ?

At first glance, I cannot see anything obvious but since you are using Eclipse, activate the TCP Monitor under Eclipse, issue your call by running you program from Eclipse and check what is sent on the wire.

Comment: "Does not work" => I get response message as "null". You see the sysout at the end it prints "Response:null", Oh and btw, I am using "myeclipse" and I cannot seem to find the TCP/IP Monitor under preferences !

Answer (score 0):

getContentDescription() "Returns: a String describing the content of this message or null if no description has been set" and NOT the content of your message.

Try this:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    reply.writeTo(out); 
    System.out.println("Response: "+out.toString());
```